# Is this structure possible to implement with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, social-networking, meteor-accounts, database

So I am coding an app in Meteor which is a mini social network for my college. The issue I am facing right now is that my data is relational. 
This web app allows people to write posts and post images and links. People who follow the user see his posts on his feed. People can share this. So the data is inter connected.

So basically

1. Users have followers
2. Followers gets the posts from the people they follow
3. They can comment and share
4. The shared post appears on the people who follow the sharer
5. Every post should be tagged from a predefined of tags
6. People who follow the tags should get the posts with the tags whether they are not following the person who wrote the post or not

Comment: yep. What else is there to say?

Answer (score 1):

You made the first – and correct – step of defining your use cases before you start to model your data.

However, you have the misconception that interrelated data needs an RDBMS.

There are several ways of [model relationships between documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/data-models-relationships/).

**Note: The following examples are heavily simplified for brevity and comprehensibility**

#### Embedding

An 1:1 relationship can be modeled simply by embedding:

```
{
    _id: "joe",
    name: "Joe Bookreader",
    address: {
          street: "123 Fake Street",
          city: "Faketon",
          state: "MA",
          zip: "12345"
        }
}
```

A 1:many relationship can be modeled by embedding, too:

```
{
    _id: "joe",
    name: "Joe Bookreader",
    phone:[
        { type:"mobile", number:"+1 2345 67890"},
        { type:"home", number:"+1 2345 987654"}
    ]
}
```

#### References

The major difference in comparison to RDBMS is that you resolve the references in your application code, as shown below.

**Implicit references**

Let's say we have publisher and books. A publisher doc may look like this

```
{
  _id: "acme",
  name: "Acme Publishing, Inc."
}
```

and a book doc may look like this

```
{
  _id:"9788636505700",
  name: "The Book of Foo",
  publisher: "acme"
}
```

Now here comes the important part: We have basically two use cases we can cover with this data. The first one being

> For "The Book of Foo", get the details for the publisher

Easy enough, since we already have "The Book of Foo" and it's values

```
db.publishers.find({_id:"acme"})
```

The other use case would be

> Which books have been published by Acme Publishing, Inc. ?

Since we have Acme Publishing, Inc's data, again, that is easy enough:

```
db.books.find({publisher:"acme"})
```

#### Explicit References

MongoDB *has* a notion of references, commonly referred to as [DBRefs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation)

However, these references are resolved by the driver and not by the MongoDB server. Personally, I have not ever used or needed it, since implicit references most of the times work perfectly.

### Example modeling for "Users make posts"

Let's say we have a user document like

```
{
  _id: "joe",
  name: "John Bookreader",
  joined: ISODate("2015-05-05T06:31:00Z"),
  …
}
```

When doing it naively, we would simply embed the posts into the user document.

However, that would limit the number of posts one can make, since there is a hardcoded size limit for BSON documents of 16MB.

So, it is pretty obvious that every post should have its own document with a reference to the author:

```
{
  _id: someObjectId,
  title: "My first post",
  text: "Some text",
  author: "joe"
}
```

However, this comes with a problem: we want to show the authors name, not his id.
For a single post, we could simply do a lookup in the users collection to get the name. But what when we want to display a list of posts? That would require a lot of queries. So instead, we use redundancy to save those queries and optimize our application:

```
{
  _id: someObjectId,
  title: "My first post",
  text: "Some text",
  author: { id:"joe", name: "Joe Bookreader"}
}
```

So for a list of posts, we can display them with the poster's name without additional queries. Only when a user wants to get details about the poster, you would look up the poster by his id. With that, we have saved a lot of queries for a common use case. You may say "Stop! What if a user changes his name?" Well, for starters, it is a relatively rare use case. And even when, it is not much of a problem. First of course, we'd have to update the user document:

```
db.users.update({"_id":"joe"},{$set:{name:"Joe A. Bookreader"}})
```

And then, we have to take an additional step:

```
db.posts.update(
    { "author.id": "joe" },
    { $set:{ "author.name": "Joe A. Bookreader" }},
    { multi: true}
)
```

Of course, this is kind of costly. But what have we done here? We optimized a common use case at the expense of a rather rare use case. A good bargain in my book.

I hope this simple example helped you to understand better on how you can approach your application's use cases with MongoDB.